# Can you retrieve travel time for a Service Appointment in Apex?

Tags: apex, fsl

Apologies, this is a hard one to present any code for, since I don't know where to start and the Salesforce documentation does not appear to give any kind of answer to this.

When a `ServiceAppointment` is scheduled and then viewed in the FSL Gantt chart, you can see a representation of the travel time required to attend that appointment.

Is there any way of retrieving these values / records in Apex?  Of seeing when a `ServiceResource` is unavailable due to the fact they are travelling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can get to this via the `AssignedResource` record that links the `ServiceResource` and `ServiceAppointment`.

It is available in the field `EstimatedTravelTime`, which represents a number of minutes.

For example, if you had the `Id` of the `ServiceAppointment`, you could:

```
SELECT EstimatedTravelTime
FROM   AssignedResource
WHERE  ServiceAppointmentId = :id
```